# onGestureEvent not being called when I try to move a box with PanGestureHandler

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I've started react native project from scratch, installed react reanimated 1.
I've pushed the repository: https://github.com/matiasmm/test-reanimated-gestures/tree/caf1af2e53605f19b466a27108ad408c95290707

I'm trying to test the pan event, but `onGestureEvent` doesn't seem to trigger. The box doesn't move (I'm testing on android).
Even, If I replace

```
<PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onPanGestureEvent}>
```

by

```
<PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={() => console.log("event called")}>
```

This console.log never executes ^

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {PanGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Reanimated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const _touchX = new Reanimated.Value(0);

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const onPanGestureEvent = Reanimated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          translationX: _touchX,
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true,
    },
  )

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onPanGestureEvent}>
        <Reanimated.View style={[styles.view, {transform: [{translateX: _touchX}]}]} />
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    flex: 1,
  },
  view: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  }
});

export default App;
```

I want to understand why the event is not triggering. What do I need to do to make the box to move when I pan on it.

Comment: Try using  "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.3"

Comment: I really need it to be react-native-reanimated 1. I'm using it in another project and need to test it with it

Answer (score 2):

Sorted it out,   it seems the problem was on android only.

This fixed it https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#android

I needed to update my MainActivity.java with these lines

Comment: Thanks Buddy. That also fixed my problem

Comment: I think they updated the documentation because I don't see anything mentioned about MainActivity.java in the new documentation and I'm still not able to fix the issue on android

Comment: @AdrianBuciuman I have added a solution

Answer (score 1):

In iOS was working fine but in android it requires to wrap your `App` with `GestureHandlerRootView` as noted in their updated documentation [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation#js)

So in your `App.js` file you should have something like this:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {/* content */}
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    )
}
```